# Individual Numpy types do not seem to preserve Endianness

Tags: python, numpy, endianness

Numpy version: 1.6.2

Can somebody explain why individual scalars of an array do not maintain the endianness set in the dtype? How do I get them to output with the right endianness?

```
>>> numpy_type1 = numpy.uint32
>>> numpy_type2 = numpy.dtype(numpy_type1).newbyteorder('>')
>>> hexdump(numpy.array([100000000], dtype = numpy_type1).tostring())
'00e1f505' # OKAY (endianness of host platform)
>>> hexdump(numpy.array([100000000], dtype = numpy_type2).tostring())
'05f5e100' # OKAY (byte swap is visible)
>>> hexdump(numpy.array([100000000], dtype = numpy_type1)[0].tostring())
'00e1f505' # OKAY (endianness of host platform)
>>> hexdump(numpy.array([100000000], dtype = numpy_type2)[0].tostring())
'00e1f505' # FAIL (no byte swapping seen)
>>> hexdump(numpy_type1(100000000).tostring())
'00e1f505' # OKAY (endianness of host platform)
>>> hexdump(numpy_type2.type(100000000).tostring())
'00e1f505' # FAIL (no byte swapping seen)
```

In the example above, notice that byte swapping is properly performed when tostring is called on a numpy array, but performs incorrectly on the scalar elements of the array?

To put it simply, I just need some way to instantiate values from the dtype and get the binary string in the correct endianness. I cannot use Python struct since it does not support float16, float128 or other exotic numeric types that Numpy does. I'd rather not do the byte swapping manually.

I would love to see this work:

```
>>> hexdump(numpy_type2.type(100000000).tostring())
'05f5e100' # OKAY (byte swapping seen)
```

Comment: Are you writing the binary strings to a file which may be read on another machine? If so, maybe hdf5 will solve your problem as it transparently converts endianness.

Answer (score 1):

For single values you can probably just as well use `struct` package. Scalars simply do not have an endianess in numpy (always system) for simplicity. However you can also use a 0-d array which will preserve the endianess. But for most results numpy converts 0-d arrays to scalars, since they are typically what you want.

Since you said you cannot use `struct`, you can use `np.array(scalar, dtype=original.dtype).tostring()` even if it is somewhat ugly.